# How can we implement a searchbox type input method in Ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, full-text-search

I want to replace :

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label color="primary" floating>Category</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]= "data.category" multiple="false" interface="popover">
        <ion-option value="0">value1</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="1">value2</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="2">value3</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="3">value4</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="4">value5</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="5">value6</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

With an ionic search type box, where I can see the entire list, search 1 and get result as `value1`, then select `value1` result which will be populated in my text field.

Can this be achieved in Ionic 2?

Comment: Try this

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic2-auto-complete

Comment: https://github.com/kadoshms/ionic2-autocomplete

Comment: Thanks!
Works fine!